# EF Conditional Query to match with whatever information available doesn't work

Tags: entity-framework

I am trying to write a query to search employees by whatever of the 3 attributes are available in my object using Linq to Entity.

My object has First name, Last name, and Date of Birth.

My query looks like this (search is the object containing partial or full info)

```
var results = ctx
    .emp
    .Where(p => 
            p.Fname == (search.Firstname ?? p.Fname)
            && p.Lname == (search.Lastname ?? p.Lname)
            && p.Dob == (search.Dob ?? p.Dob ))
```

The issue is that above query is matching employees with null values in each of those 3 columns along with the matching value. For instance if I provide `search.Firstname` to be `John`, it matches everyone with first name `John` AND everyone with `null` in first name.

How do I not match nulls in fields where a value is provided?

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tested, but won't something like this work.

`var results = ctx
    .emp
    .Where(p => (search.Firstname == null ?  p.Fname == p.Fname : p.Fname == search.Firstname) || 
(search.Lastname == null ? p.Lname == p.Lname : p.Lname == search.Lastname) || 
(search.Dob == null ? p.Dob == p.Dob : p.Dob == search.Dob))`

Please excuse the formatting. Using my mobile :)